# 500 internal server error in response in ajax . The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request

Tags: ajax

i am using following code for request and it has a long processing code in back side

```
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/admin/user/test_canvas/',
               data: {order_id:email}

           }).done(function (data){
                  if(data){
                      $(".se-pre-con").css('display','none');
                  }
              });
```

i am getting 500 internal server error in response

Comment: 500 means there is a server side problem, so you have to look there (check the server's logs)

Comment: i have checked it,there is nothing

Comment: If a server returns a 500 error, and there's no trace in the server's logs you're either looking at the wrong logfile, or this is an extremely crappy server implementation...

Comment: is this due to the ajax time out of request?

Comment: No, 500 is an error the server actively returns because it encountered an error during the processing of your call. It means an **internal server error** which is why you have to look at the server.

Comment: Not all errors are logged and not all servers log errors, that will depend on the configuration of the server, application, pages in question. You need to debug the server application to determine the error encountered. The code you've posted is client-side and the fact that you're receiving a 500 means your request is working. You now need to dig into why the server-side code is resulting in a 500 error status.

Comment: kindly make a simple server side script and check whether it works. If it works then add your code step by step. It will help you to debug it easily. Meanwhile add your server side code here also.